# How to make a link to a Flash file?

Tags: html, flash, hyperlink

How can I make a link to my Flash file?

Like an image, I can do it like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="imagefile.png" /></a>
```

I've tried to put `<a></a>` around the Flash HTML code, but it does not work.

EDIT: I found a solution. I've just put some JavaScript into the code.

Comment: you can add code with backtik "`" around it or with the "{}" icon.

Comment: Hi dude, I don't really understand why you want to add a link to a Flash file from html. If you have the Flash source files you can add a link - depending on what version of AS you use. Look up getURL (for AS2) or navigateToURL (for AS3).

Comment: I don't believe you can use HTML in that way since Flash is a plugin.

Comment: it sounds like they want to wrap an href around a swf to make the whole swf a link, similar to what they would normally do with an href around an image to hotlink it. can't be done afaik

Comment: I can't add a link to the flash file via. flash or something like that, because there is a lot of people, which are uploading there flash banner to my website. But when somebody clicks on the flash banner, i need to track the click. Thats why i need to make it with html or something like that :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for all browsers, check your path:)

Edited:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com">
    <object width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
        <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
        </embed>
    </object>
</a>
```

Comment: I need a link around the code, so i can add my tracking link when somebody are clicking on the flash banner :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
<a href="your url"><embed src="yourflashmovie" quality=high width="100" height="100">
</embed></a>
```

Comment: I want, when i click on the flash banner, i getting into my tracking link. Like i can do with standard html on a picture or something.
<a href="http://test.com/trackingcode"><img src="tracking_image.png" /></a> like that, just with flash instead